# Mixed input in quasiquotation with dplyr

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr, purrr, quasiquotes

I've taken quasiquotation to a top level.  <del>I'm close to getting my master-quasiquotator badge</del> (see edits below).  There's one chellenge bit left.

Using different inputs to create quosures with dplyr.  The end result is:

```
the_quote <- quo( if_else(!!cond_expr, !!inter_quo, !!var_expr) )
```

And I have managed to construct expressions above from a customized table with character strings, like this:

```
var_expr <- as.name(rules_df$target_col)

cond_expr <- "make == '%s'" %>% sprintf(rules_df$context_col) %>% parse_expr()

inter_quo <- quo( 
    str_detect( !!var_expr, regex(!!rules_df$phrase_col) ))
```

And where `context_col`, `phrase_col`, `target_col` are string columns in a table that I've defined the rules of engagement.

Example:

```
rules_df <- data_frame(
    context_col = "BMW", 
    phrase_col  = "Serie X(\\d)", 
    target_col  = "model")

cars_table <- data_frame(
    make = c("Mercedes", "BMW", "BMW"), 
    model = c("Viano", "Serie X5", "Z4"))
```

Tells me to find those BMW's as `Serie X5` , which I would later replace with just `X5` but that's another story.

On printing the quote, I noticed that the expressions work well, but intermediate quosure is giving an error.

```
> the_quote
<quosure>
  expr: ^if_else(marca == "BMW", 
            ^str_detect(model, regex("Serie X(\d)")), model)
  env:  000000002001DEE0

> mutate(cars_table, detect = !!the_quote)
Error: Evaluation error: `false` must be type logical, not character.
```

In the quosure I have an extra `^` which is converting the result of str_detect into a character.

How do I integrate this intermediate quosure into the outside one?

Thanks.

### Edit

Upon reviewing the solution, it ends up that the issue in this challenge was not quotation, but using `if_else` correctly in `detect` column.  That is changing logical into character, or just having the false clause act accordingly.

Thus, the alternative solution is to set `if_else(!!cond_expr, !!inter_quo, FALSE)` from the beginning.

Comment: I get some errors while copy/pasting your code.  What is `context_col`.  also, the `rules_df` is giving errors `Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""Serie X(\d"`

Comment: I fixed the example, and completed the code to replicate it.  Kept it from top to bottom, to follow the logic.  Hope that's not too bad.

Comment: The issue would be that `str_detect` return `logical` and 'model' is character` `if_else` needs both to be same class

Comment: You can chek with `cars_table %>% mutate(detect = if_else(make == "BMW", as.character(str_detect(model, regex("Serie X\\d"))), model))` and without the `as.character`

Comment: What is the desired output here if this were to work? You can't have mixed types in an atomic vector in R.

Comment: Aaahhh!!  Doesn't have to do with quotation, then.

Comment: @Diego Let me know if the correction works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to wrap with `as.character`  as the `str_detect` returns a logical class, while the `false` parameter of `if_else` is returning 'character'.  The `if_else` is particular about the class.  Thus, if we do

```
inter_quo <- quo( as.character(str_detect( !!var_expr, 
               regex(!!rules_df$phrase_col) )))
```

then it should work

```
mutate(cars_table, detect = !!the_quote)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  make     model    detect
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
#1 Mercedes Viano    Viano 
#2 BMW      Serie X5 TRUE  
#3 BMW      Z4       FALSE
```